# SharePoint Groups and AD Groups

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, groups, ad

i have one question about the SP Groups and AD Groups.
I'm trying to get all AD Groups which are in one SP Group inserted in SP.
I'm trying to get them in C#.
For example:
When i have SP Group Customers, and I added an AD Group into Customers, how can i get the AD Group from Customers in C#?
Thank you.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Assuming what MSDN says about [the Users property of SPGroup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spgroup.users.aspx) you should loop this collection to get a list of all entries. Then filter on domain property

```
SPGroup group ...
foreach (SPUser user in group.Users)
{
 if (user.IsDomainGroup)
```